# PHP: echo not working from within <a href=""> links

Tags: php, html, echo

I am calling a PHP script to download a file by clicking on HTML anchor `<a>`. I place some debugging information in that script and want to print it out during that script execution. However, this does not get printed out.

Example: I have an *HTML* anchor such as:

```
<a href="PHP/fileDownload.php?upload_id=1"> ▼ </a>
```

In the *fileDownload.php* script I have:

```
<?php
include 'ChromePhp.php';
require_once 'mysqlConnect.php';

echo "test\n test\n test\n test\n test\n test\n test\n test\n test\n test";
...
```

After I click the link, no test string contained within `echo` statement is printed out.

Could anybody clarify this for me, please? Is there a way to make `echo` statement work in my situation?

Comment: Enable error reporting first. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script and refresh the page.

Comment: What headers do you send out?

Comment: @AmalMurali: I did include those two commands. I did page refresh, however no change. No error neither. What is important, that script later contains file download. The file gets downloaded, so the script gets executed. The problem is, that it wont print anything on the screen.

Comment: @Bunkai.Satori Open the downloaded file. Do you find the strings there?

Comment: Then its surely because of headers

Comment: http://www.symkat.com/force-download-with-http-headers

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, Hi Hanky. I use later on that page only one header: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"uploaded.pdf\"");` It is couple of lines below the mentioned `echo`. Is there any issue with my header?

Comment: Yes, remove that header and try debugging again

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky, yes, indeed. :-) Would you be willing to write short answer? I can mark it as the accepted answer and close this question. If you would hlep me understand what is going on, and if there is any workaround to use my header and still see 'echo' output, that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: You claim: "After I click the link, no test string contained within echo statement is printed out.". But you do not say what does happen. So what?

Comment: @arkascha: good point, nothing happens on the screen. The script itself contains file download routine. The file gets downloaded appropriately. But as mentioned above, the problem lies that I have used headers forcing browser to save the data.

Comment: Ok, so something IS happening. And is the debugging output inside the downloaded file or not? You cannot output to the browser display _and_ download a file with a simple anchor as you do. It is either or.

Comment: @arkascha, interesting: I have found the `echo` content withing the downloaded file. However, no debugging information at all. I inserted it at the beginning of my script: `<?php ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);...`

Comment: Well, what "debugging information" would you expect? Everything is working without error, from a technical point of view.

Comment: @arkascha: one possibility would be outputting nothing as you said, or a positive message, such as: 'OK'. But I get it, once everything works, the above debug info returns nothing.

Comment: I think you really should read a bit about errors in php: what you call "debug info" is what is usually logged into a file on server side: it is errors and warnings, incidents php wants to inform you about. This has why it is called "display_errors" and "error_reporting" and not something like "debug_info".

Comment: Ah, and btw: it usually makes much more sense not to display such errors, since that breaks the page layout, but to log errors into a file on server side and monitor that file for new content.

Comment: @arkascha, understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"uploaded.pdf\"");
```

Its because the HTTP headers, which you are sending like above, are telling the browser to expect a file to be downloaded. They are not telling browser to expect HTML content (default). Therefore the content you are sending in an echo is not getting displayed.

Both won't work together correctly although I'm sure you can find any work around but the point is that you only need those echo's while debugging so you can disable the mentioned header call while debugging and once everything is set, enable that again so file can download.

Comment: But then it should be contained in the file downloaded.

Comment: I'm sure it must be there then.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm, the test string was in the file downloaded. It was at the beginning of the file. This is interesting new info for me. Thanks +1.